# Just how many printf and scanf variants are there?

Tags: c

There are so many different versions of `printf` and `scanf` in C that it brings out a chuckle in me. Let's start:

- `printf`: original implementation; uses `format` then the values as arguments
- `fprintf`: the same, but takes a `FILE` pointer before `format`
- `sprintf`: takes a `char` pointer before `format`
- `snprintf`: same as above, but limits size written for buffer overflow safety
- `vprintf`: like `printf` but takes a `va_list` of value arguments
- `vfprintf`: the `va_list` equivalent of `fprintf`
- `vsprintf`: the `va_list` equivalent of `sprintf`
- `vsnprintf`: the `va_list` equivalent of `snprintf`
- `asprintf`: takes a `char **` before `format` and allocates memory on the pointer
- `vasprintf`: the same as above, but uses `va_list`
- `scanf`: reads `format` into arguments after it from `stdin`
- `fscanf`: takes a `FILE` pointer before `format`, reading from it instead
- `sscanf`: takes a `char` pointer before `format`, reading from it instead
- `vscanf`: the `va_list` function analogical to `scanf`
- `vfscanf`: the `va_list` function analogical to `fscanf`
- `vsscanf`: the `va_list` function analogical to `sscanf`

Thanks to **dreamlax**, the ones that work with `wchar_t`:

- `wprintf`: original implementation using `wchar_t` everywhere that `char *` was
- `fwprintf`: writes to a `FILE` pointer before `format`, using `wchar_t`
- `swprintf`: writes to a `char` pointer before `format`, using `wchar_t`
- `vwprintf`: writes to `stdin`, taking a `va_list` instead of normal arguments
- `vfwprintf`: writes to a `FILE` pointer, taking a `va_list` instead of normal arguments
- `vswprintf`: writes to a `char` pointer, taking a `va_list` instead of normal arguments

Are there any more?

Comment: great list, i dont knew most of them. Thanks

Comment: No problem. Unlike the person who voted to close this question, I thought this would grow to become a handy reference.

Comment: I think it is a useful reference, but perhaps should be CW?

Comment: Wow -- the asprintf variant is pretty awesome. I have allocated a temporary buffer for sprintf stuff a lot in my time.

Comment: It should be noted that `asprintf` is a GNU extension, not a standard function. But it's easily implemented using `snprintf`.

Comment: Does this mean that it'll only compile on `gcc`? I'm actually OK with this ;)

Comment: @Delan: It means it will only work on systems that use GNU's implementation of the standard C library (i.e. GNU/Linux).

Comment: Voting to reopen, as one would expect. I mean, come on, it *is* a real question. I'm asking for the variants of `printf` so I can make a nice reference here.

Comment: Closed as not a real question?! "It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form." There is no ambiguity, the question is not broad or incomplete, nor is it rhetorical. If it's difficult to tell what's being asked, perhaps a lesson on reading comprehension is in order.

Comment: @dreamlax, thanks for the reopen vote.

Comment: Hey, this question came up second only to Wikipedia/printf on a Google search for "printf variants".

Answer (score 3):

While there are a lot, usually all but `vfprintf` and `vfwprintf` are simply wrappers for these two which pass an appropriate `FILE *` (possibly a special one setup for writing to a string instead of to a file on disk) and optionally call `va_start` and `va_end` (depending on if they're the "v" version or the plain version.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing all of the ones that operate on [`wchar_t`](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/fwprintf.html).

Comment: Yay, let's double the amount of functions! *adds them to the list*